# use polar notation to write $(2+3i)^6$ in $a+bi$

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, algebra-precalculus

So we are given several formulas and they are all quite confusing:

$x = rcos(\theta)$ and $y=risin(\theta)$

$r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$

$z=e^{i\theta}=r(cos(\theta)+isin(\theta)$

$r$ is quite easy to find $r=\sqrt{3^2+2^2}=\sqrt{13}$

$\theta=arctan(\frac{a}{b})=arctan(\frac{2}{3})=.58800$

I think my professor wants me to utilize the equation:

$z=re^{i\theta}$

if that's the case then:

$\sqrt{13}(cos(\frac{2}{3})+isin(\frac{2}{3}))$

$cos(\frac{2}{3})=.78588$

$sin(\frac{2}{3})=.61836$

so $\sqrt{13}e^{i(sin(\frac{2}{3})+cos(\frac{2}{3})}$

then I:

$\Big(\sqrt{13}e^{i(sin(\frac{2}{3})+cos(\frac{2}{3})}\Big)^6$

then convert back to polar

Am I at all on the right track? this is from my abstract algebra class. The changing forms is completely new to me. Ive used polar coordinates in calculus $3$ Can someone simplify this? I am better with formulas than I am with a geometric understanding. But if someone can show me an algorithm either algebraically or geometrically that would be great.

Comment: You have an unclosed parenthesis at "$\sqrt{13}e^{i(sin(\frac{2}{3})+cos(\frac{2}{3})}$" but presumably $i$ is the coefficient of $\sin$ only.

Comment: Does your worksheet specifically say $\arctan\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)$?

Comment: no it did not I think I came along that myself its supposed to be $arctan(\frac{b}{a})$ correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Your third equation you wrote:  "$z=e^{i\theta}=r(cos(\theta)+isin(\theta)$"  That is incorrect.  It should be "$z=re^{i\theta}=r(cos(\theta)+isin(\theta)$"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning a complex number, $a+bi$, into polar, or modulus-argument, form should give you $r\left(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta\right)$, where the modulus $r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ is the distance of $a+bi$ from $0$ and the argument, $\theta=\arctan\frac{b}{a}$, (assuming $a,b>0$) is the angle from $0$. You can see how $\theta$ is calculated with trigonometry and the figure below.

[image]

So, you correctly calculated $r=\sqrt{13}$ but had $a,b$ the wrong way around when calculating $\theta$. You would also need to keep the $\arctan(\cdot)$ function when plugging $\theta$ into $\sin(\cdot)$ and $\cos(\cdot)$ - it doesn't disappear. Lastly, you've referenced [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) is a powerful theorem for complex numbers and says that $\left(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta\right)=\color{red}{e^{i\theta}}$, so you either have $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$ or combine them into $e^{\theta}$. You don't have all three at once. Personally, I'd suggest using avoiding $e^{i\theta}$ and instead using [De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula) until you feel more comfortable with complex numbers.

Other than those three mistakes, you seem to be on the right track.

---

> How do I convert back to $a+bi$ form?

Applying de Moivre's formula tells you that $$\left[\sqrt{13}\left(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta\right)\right]^6=\underbrace{(\sqrt{13})^6}_{\text{modulus}}\left[\cos\underbrace{(6\theta)}_{\text{argument}}+i\sin(6\theta)\right]$$

So this is another number in polar form. Reverse the definitions of the modulus and argument to find the new $a$ and $b$.

> Is there a good article.

- [Wikipedia: Complex number # Polar complex plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Polar_complex_plane)
- [University of Salford: Polar representation of complex numbers](http://www.cse.salford.ac.uk/physics/gsmcdonald/pp/PPLATOResources/h-flap/M3_2t.pdf)

Comment: then how do I convert back to $a+bi$ form? is there a good article?

Comment: @K.Gibson See the addenda on my answer.

Comment: okay so after looking at the article I still couldn't find anything that showed me how to go from Euler's formula back to complex numbers form. Maybe I am missing something fundamental

Comment: @K.Gibson I'd say avoid Euler's formula. Just use de Moivre's formula with $\sin$ and $\cos$.

Comment: "Maybe I am missing something fundamental"  I think you are:   Polar format is $r e^{i\theta}$.  Now $e^{i\theta}$ in complex number form is $\cos \theta + i\sin \theta$ and so $re^{i\theta}$ in complex number form is $r*\cos\theta + i r*\sin \theta$.  In other words.  If $z = r*e^{i\theta}$ then $z = a + bi$ where $a = r*\cos \theta$ and $b = r*\sin \theta$  That's all there is to it.  It's a smidgen harder to get the other way. If $z = a+bi$ then $z =re^{i\theta}$ where $r=\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ and $\theta = \arctan \frac ba$.  That's all there is to it.

Comment: Thank you @fleablood very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Actually, $2+3i=\sqrt{13}\exp i\theta$ with $\theta=\arctan\frac32=0.983$, so $\cos6\theta=\cos5.897=0.926$ and $\sin6\theta=-0.377$. Multiplying by $\sqrt{13}^6$, $(2+3i)^6=2035-828i$.

Comment: where did you get $6\theta$ in both $sin$ and $cos$?

Comment: @K.Gibson de Moivre's theorem.